# Parsing a string into variables batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I need to retreive from the string

```
"Y:\CR_delete_day_types\TEST\XXXX\Extract_prod\saleable_capacity_2013-07-18_1319_153.dat"
```

the part `"_2013-07-18_1319"` and put it in a variable so that it can be passed in parameter in the rest of the batch script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "string=Y:\CR_delete_day_types\TEST\XXXX\Extract_prod\saleable_capacity_2013-07-18_1319_153.dat"
FOR %%x IN ("%string%") DO FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=_" %%a IN ("%%~nx") DO SET "this=_%%c_%%d"
ECHO %this%
```